# untitled section even if there is a heading

Tags: html, html-heading

I have this little part of markup:

```
<section class="middle tab-bar-section">
    <h2 class="title">Lorem ipsum</h2>
</section>
```

If I run it through an HTML5 outliner, the section is untitled, like this:

```
1. Untitled Section
    1. Lorem ipsum
```

Shouldent the h2 tag be the sections title?

Comment: Try H1 instead, you can use one H1 in every section. Not 100% sure if this will be the section title then though..

Comment: Nope, the use of h1 resulted the same